# Delete a row from showed up dataGridView?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have to build APP which search,update,delete and add information in database with 3 tables. Im using SQL CE, i've made the search and add button and they work.

I have 1 search button and 3 textboxes for each table which shows up an datagridview for the table in which im searching. I've searched hard but seems like i cant find a solution, i want to make an delete button which deletes from the datagridview which popup /really sorry for my english/ i hope u get it.

I've found a way to delete from only 1 dgv and actually it doesnt even save the dgv. Here is the code im using for the search button, im not asking someone to write it for me but only for a tip how to do it.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "" && textBox3.Text == "")
    {
        dataGridView1.Hide();
        dataGridView2.Hide();
        dataGridView3.Hide();
        MessageBox.Show("Insert something to search!");
        return;
    }
    else if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox3.Text == "")
    {
        try
        {
            this.institutionTableAdapter.SearchNameInst(this.database1DataSet1.Institution, textBox2.Text);
            dataGridView3.Show();
            dataGridView2.Hide();
            dataGridView1.Hide();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else if (textBox2.Text == "" && textBox3.Text == "")
    {
        try
        {
            this.studentsTableAdapter.SearchStudName(this.database1DataSet1.Students, textBox1.Text);
            dataGridView3.Hide();
            dataGridView2.Show();
            dataGridView1.Hide();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "")
    {
        try
        {
            this.typeinstTableAdapter.SearchNameTown(this.database1DataSet1.Typeinst, textBox3.Text);
            dataGridView3.Hide();
            dataGridView2.Hide();
            dataGridView1.Show();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to delete one row from one dvg? 
And the database should be updated to. Do I understand you right?

Comment: Not really, sry for the mistkake. I want to delete the selected row in the datagridview which im using atm with 1 button only and then changes to be saved.

Comment: can´t you implement the code, whitch I set in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

the following code delete the current row in ONE datagridview:

**CODE**

```
DataGridViewRow deleteRow = grid.CurrentRow;

grid.CurrentRow.Selected = false;

grid.Rows[deleteRow+1].Selected = true;

grid.Rows.RemoveAt(deleteRow);
```

If you want to update your MySql-Database you have to check the row-ID and call the delete-methode in MySql like:

**CODE**

```
 try
 {
                  dt = new DataTable();

                  using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=test;password=1234"))
                  {

                      conn.Open();
                      using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                      {
                          cmd.Connection = conn;

                          string tabvalue = grid.Rows[grid.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                          cmd.CommandText = ("DELETE FROM `Table`.`currenttable` WHERE `ID` ='" +      tabvalue + "';");
                          MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                          da.Fill(dt);
                      }
                      conn.Close();
                  }
              }

catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

You have to change the DataGridView name and the current table name, but I hope this example will solve your problem! If it don´t save your prob. please let a comment then I´ll try to write some code for you!  Have a nice day.

Comment: It doesnt solve my problem.. all 3 gridviews are not visible, for example i want to search for students and when the datagridview for the table "students" popup i want to be able to delete the cell or row i want with the delete button, but also with this delete button i want to be able also to delete in the other 2 gridviews when im searching in them if u get it now.